# How can I export each individual Raster out of an ESRI Rastercatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster-catalog

I have a managed raster catalog (ArcGIS 10.0) which contains many images. I need to migrate these to another GIS and have to export them individually. As far as I can see, I can only export all images to a raster catalog. Is there a way to iterate through each item and export them singularly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a simple model. Make sure the input to the iterator is the full path name to the raster catalog rather than the layer name from ArcMap. Also tick the recursive check box. Use in-line substitution to pass the raster name out.

[image: Model]